# Bedeutung von "über den Tresen gehen"

Tags: meaning

> An den ersten zwei Verkaufstagen ging das iPhone 270 000 Mal über den Tresen.

In welcher Hinsicht ist das ein Synonym von "verkauft werden", also ist dies ein umgangssprachlicher Ausdruck oder schwingt etwas anderes mit?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Die Wendung *über den Tresen gehen* für *verkauft werden* tritt in der Umgangssprache kaum auf. Sehr häufig ist sie jedoch in journalistischen Texten zu finden.

Eine besondere Konnotation (Kritik, Irionie, Bewunderung, Verachtung oder was immer) ist für mein Verständnis damit nicht verbunden. *Über den Tresen gehen* ist somit ein relativ neutraler Ausdruck, ähnlich wie

> an den Mann bringen
>
> absetzen

und ganz anders als

> verramschen
>
> verscherbeln
>
> verkloppen

die einen despektierlichen Ton haben und für "billig verkaufen" stehen oder

> verjubeln

das die andere Seite bezeichnet: das leichtfertige, sorglose schnelle Ausgeben von Geld für kurzfristige Zwecke.

In journalistischen Texten wird oft versucht, Wörter, die des Themas wegen zwangsläufig häufig vorkommen (wie *verkaufen* in Artikeln im Wirtschaftsteil der Zeitung oder *Auto* in Artikeln über die Automobilindustrie), ab und zu durch Synonyme zu ersetzen, in der Hoffnung, dass der Text dann schöner zu lesen sein werde.

Es gibt einige solcher Ersatzbegriffe, die überhaupt nur in journalistischen Texten vorkommen wie "Grautier" für Esel oder "Main-Metropole" für Frankfurt. Solche Wörter verwendet außerhalb der Zeitung kein Mensch.

<sup>(Ich habe manchmal den Eindruck, der eine oder andere Zeitungsschreiber macht sich einen Spaß daraus, solche Wörter einzusetzen, wohlwissend, dass das eine Marotte ist. Aber in den Redaktionen ist man sehr strengen Regeln und Vorgaben ausgesetzt, da kommt es schon mal vor, dass man an den wenigen Stellen, die es ermöglichen, verrückte Sachen macht, ums sich Luft zu schaffen. - Ich hatte mal einen Kollegen, der machte sich zum Sport, in buchstäblich jedem seiner Artikel einmal das Wort "unisono" zu verwenden.)</sup>

Der Ausdruck "über den Tresen gehen" gehört nicht zu diesen Marotten-Begriffen, aber er wird dir im Alltag kaum über die Zunge gehen.

Comment: Diese Wendung habe ich mit "Theken" auch gesehen, glaube allerdings, dass es mit Akkusativ verwedet ist. Wäre dieser Fall nicht richtiger?

Comment: Du meinst "über die Theke gehen"? - Das wäre eine Variante des standardmäßigen "über den Tresen gesen". Tresen = die Ladentheke, also der Tisch, auf dem die Kasse steht und über den ggf. die Ware gereicht wird.

Comment: Genau, über die Theke, mit Akkusativ. Über den Tresen ist aber in Dativ, warum?

Comment: @Beta Das ist beides Akkusativ.

Comment: Wenn es "über die Theken" (die!) ist, dann ist es Plural (aber in der Tat immer noch Akkusativ). - "Über die Theken gehen" wäre dann eine recht kreative Ausformung der Wendung: Der Autor suggeriert, dass hier mehrere Ladengeschäfte im Spiel sind, nicht nur eines.

Comment: Also, wir haben hier mit nur einem Tresen zu tun... Ich habe dies fälschlich als Plural dativ verstanden. Soo doof.

Answer (score 4):

Ein Tresen ist entweder

1. ein Verkaufstisch in einem Geschäft

   > Vor dem **Tresen** bildete sich schon eine lange Schlange ungeduldiger Kunden.
   >   Die Verkäuferin hinter dem **Tresen** empfahl mir die Luxusvariante.
   >   Wortlos schob mir der grimmige Kerl die bestellten Schaufeln über den **Tresen**.

oder

2. Der Ausschanktisch in einem Gastronomiebetrieb
   In dieser Bedeutung sind »Theke«, »Schank« oder »Schanktisch« und auch »Bar« gerne verwendete Synonyme (wobei *Bar* noch eine zweite Bedeutung haben kann, nämlich das ganze Lokal; das ist hier aber nicht gemeint)

   > Jimmy stand am **Tresen** und trank einen Whiskey.
   >   Als die Party in der kleinen Kneipe ihren Höhepunkt erreichte, kletterte Margot auf den **Tresen** und tanzte dort.

Der Ausdruck »etwas geht über den Tresen« hängt mit Bedeutung 1 zusammen, und stammt aus der Zeit, als in Geschäften zwischen dem Verkäufer und dem Kunden ein Tisch stand, der meist sogar fix am Boden montiert war, und nicht selten auch um Vitrinen erweitert war. Die Bezeichnung für so einen Verkaufstisch ist »Tresen«.

Der Kunde auf der einen Seite bestellte eine Waren, und der Verkäufer ging dann nach hinten ins Lager, holte die Ware, und legte sie dann auf den Tisch. Der Kunde bezahlte während die Ware noch am Tresen lag, und nahm sie anschließend an sich. Dabei bewegt sich die Ware also über den Tresen, was mit »die Ware *geht* über den Tresen« umschrieben wird. In einigen Geschäften ist das auch heute noch so üblich.

Bei Onlinegeschäften und in Selbstbedienungsgeschäften findet dieser Vorgang jedoch nicht mehr physisch statt. Hier handelt es sich also um eine Phrase, die als Synonym für »verkaufen« verwendet wird.

Das Wort *»die Theke«* ist übrigens in beiden Bedeutungen ein Synonym für *»der Tresen«,* wobei ich den Eindruck habe, dass im Fall des Verkaufstisches *Tresen* häufiger verwendet wird als *Theke*, während das beim Schanktisch genau umgekehrt ist.